# _rewrite section stringified function isn't working proprely

Tags: couchdb-2.0

I tried CouchDB's rewrite function, see: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/rewrites.html at "Rewrite section a is stringified function", but it seems it doesn't work. I used the example as a base.

This is mydb _design/router rewrites function:

```
function (req2) {
 var path = req2.path.slice(4);

 return {path:"../../../"+path.join("/")};
};
```

mydb design document:

```
{
 "_id": "_design/router",
 "_rev": "1-ff8b2d9e12f41de38495d3460e8c10ad",
 "rewrites": "function (req2) {\r\n    var path = req2.path.slice(4);\r\n\r\n      return {path:\"../../../\"+path.join(\"/\")};\r\n}"
}
```

this code supposed to pass through all requests made to endpoint mydb/_design/router/_rewrite/*

example:

GET localhost:5984/mydb/_design/router/_rewrite/mydb/_all_docs
reroutes to  mydb/_all_docs

The GET requests are working fine (as expected)

But the POST, PUT, DELETE requests are hanging (no response!).

example:

POST localhost:5984/mydb/_design/router/_rewrite/mydb

```
Content-Type:application/json
body:{"foo": "bar"}
```

No error message returns just hanging.

The above request works fine without rewrite! (POST localhost:5984/mydb inserts a new document {"foo": "bar"})

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here? If it is a bug where can I report it?

My specs: Win7 64bit, CouchDB 2.0.0

Thanks!